# Exclude non English rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to drop all rows from a data frame where the string value in a certain column is not written in English. Example: I got a column named "text" in my data frame and I want to drop all rows that don't return "en" when using langdetect on that field. (langdetect uses a function .detect(text) and returns "en" if the text is written in English).

I am relatively new to python/pandas and I spent the last 2 days trying to figure out how loc and lambda functions work but I can't find a solution to my problem. I tried the following functions:

```
languageDetect = ld.detect(df.text.str) 
df.loc[languageDetect, "text"] = 'en'
```

Different approach, I tried to apply the ld.detect(text) function to the row and save it as a new data frame but it didn't work.

```
df['new'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: ld.detect(x))
```

I am working with huge files (over millions of rows sometimes) so iterating the rows with a "for" is not really a viable solution for my problem. I did try it though and it worked but I couldn't find a way to create a new data frame with the values.

```
 for index, row in df.iterrows():
            if row['text']:
                try:
                    if "en" in ld.detect(row['text']):
                        print(index, row['text'])
                except:
                    pass
```

Can anyone help me out? I'd like to create a new data frame with all rows that return "en" when langdetect.detect(textColumn)=='en'. Is this even possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just do the following, if you want to replace errors by false:

```
def is_en(txt):
    try:
        return ld.detect(x)=='en'
    except:
        return false

df = df[df['text'].apply(is_en)]
```

Comment: I tried this but I get the following error: langdetect.lang_detect_exception.LangDetectException: No features in text.

Comment: Probably because there is a NaN or an empty string, what do you want if this is the case?

Comment: Can you still reply to this, they closed my thread but I can't find a similar one? I tried removing NaN or replacing it with empty string but I still get the same error. I think it's due to some fields having no words or maybe just emojis, is there a way to skip errors?

Comment: Just edited, see if that's what you want